# The domain of every function is a subset of R.

Tags: functions, real-numbers

just wondering if this statement is true or false? And can anyone give an example // Counter Example if the statement is true or false respectively

Comment: What kind of the function did you mean?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then there is a function $f$ with domain $A$ and codomain $B$.

Comment: x^2; 3x+2;  |y|=x

Comment: @user296602 Unless $B$ is empty and $A$ is not.

Comment: I expect that $R$ stands for the set of real numbers. The answer to your question is "no". Functions do not have necessarily real numbers as input.

Comment: Normally you are looking for a proof of a true statement and a counter-example when the statement is false.

Comment: @MarkBennet hence the respectively ...

Comment: @drhab Can you give a counter example to back this statement? Cause it's still unclear to me as to how i would show this in an example

Comment: For example, the Riemann Integral over the interval $[0, 1]$ is a function, from the set of continuous functions defined on $[0, 1]$, to the real numbers. That is, its inputs are functions, not real numbers!

Comment: @JakeRivishero multiple examples in the answers already given ...

Comment: Just let $A$ be a set that is **not** a subset of $\mathbb R$ (sets like that exist). Then we have the identity function $\text{id}_A:A\to A$ that is prescribed by $a\mapsto a$. Its domain is $A$ which is not a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - my point is that an example of a true statement is different from a proof.

Comment: @MarkBennet okay you got me there but it's pretty easy to think of counter examples if you know the math.

Answer (score 1):

I can just define a function that takes ordered pairs as input by $f((1,2))=3$.  Its domain is $\{(1,2)\}$, which is not a subset of $\Bbb R$

Comment: at least you didn't do one between two Cartesian products.

Answer (score 1):

from my comments  if you start with the complex numbers their distance to the origin in the complex plane is a real number so we then have a domain of the complex numbers and a codomain of the reals.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously false.

Suppose a function is defined on a plane. Then its domain is a plane, which certainly is not a subset of reals. As a result the domain of any function of a <s>complex agrument</s> complex number is not a subset of reals.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html  shows that complex argument may not be the best use of words here.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Right. Fixed. Thank you.